# Weird terminology in Overleaf's source code

Tags: overleaf

Does anyone know if there has been some recent update on Overleaf's LaTeX editor? When I use the math mode, it turns out that it works a bit different from before. For instance,
instead of the usual notation

[image: screenshot from given example]

it appears this

[image]

and the problem is not about this new fancy notation, what happens is that it is really uncomfortable to write (try it and you'll see what I'm talking about). Does anybody have the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please send Overleaf questions to Overleaf (support@overleaf.com) - I'm a member of the support team, and we're quite happy to answer questions like this.

This is usually caused by a browser plugin (it isn't Overleaf behaviour).

If you have a browser plugin that automatically compiles LaTeX (like "TeX all the Things" for Chrome), it will try to render your source code as you type it. This can be very distracting, so we'd advise that you disable the plugin when you use Overleaf.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and I'll take it into account the next time!